# Equivalence between statements about a metric space (continuity, clopen and compact sets) - additional questions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a little modified version of this question: [Equivalent statements about a metric space (homeomorphism, continuity, cluster points, clopen sets and compacts)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048700/equivalent-statements-about-a-metric-space-homeomorphism-continuity-cluster-p)

The problem is that we haven't done cluster points, and so we have to prove that $c) \Rightarrow e)$, and also I can't use the proof that $f) \Rightarrow a)$ given there, for the same reason.

In addition to that, I have a question about explanation as to why a) implies b) provided at this question. This proves that every function from metric space $M$ with discrete metric to $M$ with its regular metric $d$ is continuous? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: I fixed a typo in sein's proof of $(c) \implies (e)$ so the extra question you posted on that is no longer needed. You proposed a proof by contradiction there but the proof below is cleaner and better and shows we only need $M$ to be Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(f) \implies (a)$ is quite easy. Assume that $(M,d)$ has only finite compact subsets. So assume $M$ is not discrete, this means that for some $p \in M$, the  set $\{p\}$ is not open (if all singletons *were* open, all subsets would be open and $M$ would have the discrete topology, which it has not).

So for all $n \in \Bbb N$ we have that $B(p, \frac1n) \nsubseteq \{p\}$ (or we'd have shown that $\{p\}$ is open) so for all $n \in \Bbb N$  we have some $p_n \in M$ so that $d(p_n,p) < \frac1n$ (in $B(p, \frac1n)$ but $p_n \neq p$ (not in $\{p\}$). It's immediate that $p_n \to p$ in $(M,d)$ and also that the set $K:=\{p_n\mid n \in \Bbb N\} \cup \{p\}$ is infinite. It's also clear that $K$ is compact (any open cover of $K$ has an open subset that covers $p$ and this neighbourhood of $p$ contains all but finitely many $p_n$ etc etc. This holds in any topological space).
But then $K$ contradicts $(f)$ (so we show the implication via the contrapositive $\lnot(a) \implies \lnot(f)$, really) QED.

It's a minor variant of the given proof but not mentioning cluster points or limit points.

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes so much more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

So given that you understand that $a\implies b\implies c$, we might prove that $c\implies a$ and that $a\implies e$. So we want to show, given $c)$ that every singleton is open. Let $a\in M$ and $b\in M$ such that $a\neq b$ and take two opens $a\in U_a$ and $b\in U_b$ such that $U_a\cap U_b=\emptyset$. Furthermore define the function $f: M\to M$ by $f(a)=b$, $f(b)=a$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x$ not equal to $a$ or $b$. Then $f$ is a bijection and hence a homeormorfism. Now by continuity $f^{-1}[U_b]$ is open and equals $(U_b\setminus \{b\}\cup\{a\})$ and $U_a$ is also open and so $(U_b\setminus \{b\}\cup\{a\})\cap U_a=\{a\}$ is also open. So any singleton is open, which is what we wanted.

Now we might prove $a\implies e$. We know that any singleton is open. Let $A\subset M$, then $\bigcup_{a\in A}a$ is open. Furthermore $\bigcup_{b\in M\setminus A}b$ is open and hence $A$ is clopen.

And yes your understanding of the question is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You have understood the "proof" of $ a) \Rightarrow b)$ well, but the proof you're looking at doesn't prove $ a) \Rightarrow b)$, since we're looking to prove that every function $ f:(M, d) \to (M, d) $ is continuous. What op has proved holds regardless of the assumption a).

Comment: Hi Nikola. You address "You" here. Who is this "You"?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear.

Comment: @NikolaBurbakić I am inclined to agree with the previous comment.  You seem to be replying to another user, not answering the question at the top of the page.  To whom are you addressing this "answer"?

Comment: I'm not replying to an answer. I'm answering the question posted by @dorotea26, "I have a question about explanation as to why a) implies b) provided at this question", and I think I've answered that question.